# How to bundle time series data into 24 hour interval in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file which contains some data

```
,date,location,device,provider,cpu,mem,load,drops,id,latency,gw_latency,upload,download,sap_drops,sap_latency,alert_id
389,2018-02-13 09:20:17.572685+00:00,ASA,10.11.100.1,BOM,4.0,23.0,0.25,0.0,,,,,,,,
390,2018-02-13 09:20:21.836284+00:00,ASA,10.11.100.1,COD,4.0,23.0,2.08,0.0,,,,,,,,
391,2018-02-13 09:30:59.401178+00:00,ASA,10.11.100.1,COD,5.0,23.0,8.0,0.0,,,,,,,,
392,2018-02-13 09:31:03.667730+00:00,ASA,10.11.100.1,COD,5.0,23.0,3.5,0.0,,,,,,,,
393,2018-02-13 09:41:14.666626+00:00,ASA,10.11.100.1,BOM,4.0,23.0,0.5,0.0,,,,,,,,
394,2018-02-13 09:41:18.935061+00:00,ASA,10.11.100.1,DAE,4.0,23.0,3.0,0.0,,,,,,,,
395,2018-02-13 09:50:17.491014+00:00,ASA,10.11.100.1,DAE,5.0,23.0,8.25,0.0,,,,,,,,
396,2018-02-13 09:50:21.751805+00:00,BBB,10.11.100.1,BOM,5.0,23.0,2.75,0.0,,,,,,,,
397,2018-02-13 10:00:18.387647+00:00,BBB,10.11.100.1,CXU,5.0,23.0,2.0,0.0,,,,,,,,
398,2018-02-13 10:00:22.847626+00:00,ASA,10.11.100.1,BOM,5.0,23.0,3.17,0.0,,,,,,,,
399,2018-02-13 10:10:17.521642+00:00,BBB,10.11.100.1,DAE,5.0,23.0,1.0,0.0,,,,,,,,
400,2018-02-13 10:10:21.786720+00:00,BBB,10.11.100.1,DAE,5.0,23.0,2.42,0.0,,,,,,,,
401,2018-02-13 10:14:38.085999+00:00,BBB,10.11.100.1,CXU,4.0,23.0,0.25,0.0,,,,,,,,
..................................................................................
..................................................................................
```

As you can see there are lot of entries for the date `2018-02-13` across several time intervals.I want to put these into `24` hour interval where each hour will contain one value (averaged value).This is what I did

```
df_next = df.loc['2018-04-13'].resample('H')["cpu"].mean().fillna(0)
```

But the for the date `2018-04-13`, the data collected was only upto `10:00` hrs (last entry was made at `10:14:38`).So it only gives me upto that.For some other dates, if the data was collected from `9:00` onwards, then I only get the per hour interval from `9:00` only.

How do I get a complete `24` hours interval starting from `00:00` for a date no matter at what time data was collected?So basically its going to assign `0` for the hours when data was not collected and `mean` for the hour when the data was collected?

So basically I want something like this

```
381,2018-02-13 00:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
382,2018-02-13 01:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
383,2018-02-13 02:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
384,2018-02-13 03:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
385,2018-02-13 04:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
386,2018-02-13 05:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
387,2018-02-13 06:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
388,2018-02-13 07:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
388,2018-02-13 08:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 

389,2018-02-13 09:20:17.572685+00:00,ASA,10.11.100.1,BOM,4.0,23.0,0.25,0.0,,,,,,,,
390,2018-02-13 09:20:21.836284+00:00,ASA,10.11.100.1,COD,4.0,23.0,2.08,0.0,,,,,,,,
391,2018-02-13 09:30:59.401178+00:00,ASA,10.11.100.1,COD,5.0,23.0,8.0,0.0,,,,,,,,
392,2018-02-13 09:31:03.667730+00:00,ASA,10.11.100.1,COD,5.0,23.0,3.5,0.0,,,,,,,,
393,2018-02-13 09:41:14.666626+00:00,ASA,10.11.100.1,BOM,4.0,23.0,0.5,0.0,,,,,,,,
394,2018-02-13 09:41:18.935061+00:00,ASA,10.11.100.1,DAE,4.0,23.0,3.0,0.0,,,,,,,,
395,2018-02-13 09:50:17.491014+00:00,ASA,10.11.100.1,DAE,5.0,23.0,8.25,0.0,,,,,,,,
396,2018-02-13 09:50:21.751805+00:00,BBB,10.11.100.1,BOM,5.0,23.0,2.75,0.0,,,,,,,,
397,2018-02-13 10:00:18.387647+00:00,BBB,10.11.100.1,CXU,5.0,23.0,2.0,0.0,,,,,,,,
398,2018-02-13 10:00:22.847626+00:00,ASA,10.11.100.1,BOM,5.0,23.0,3.17,0.0,,,,,,,,
399,2018-02-13 10:10:17.521642+00:00,BBB,10.11.100.1,DAE,5.0,23.0,1.0,0.0,,,,,,,,
400,2018-02-13 10:10:21.786720+00:00,BBB,10.11.100.1,DAE,5.0,23.0,2.42,0.0,,,,,,,,
401,2018-02-13 10:14:38.085999+00:00,BBB,10.11.100.1,CXU,4.0,23.0,0.25,0.0,,,,,,,,

402,2018-02-13 11:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
403,2018-02-13 12:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
404,2018-02-13 13:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
405,2018-02-13 14:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
406,2018-02-13 15:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
407,2018-02-13 16:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
408,2018-02-13 17:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
409,2018-02-13 18:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
410,2018-02-13 19:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
411,2018-02-13 20:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
412,2018-02-13 21:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
413,2018-02-13 22:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
414,2018-02-13 23:00:00.000000+00:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

As you can see it fills up the rest of the hours and keeps their values as `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#get Series only for hourly data
#remove non exist hours by dropna 
a = df.resample('H')["cpu"].mean().dropna()
#create all posible hours by first min and max value floor to 0 and 23 hour
rng = pd.date_range(a.index.min().floor('d'), 
                    a.index.max().floor('d') + pd.Timedelta(23, unit='h'), freq='H')
#get all missing index values - missing hours
diff_idx = rng.difference(a.index)

#join new DataFrame with missing values to original, last sorting for correct ordering
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(index=diff_idx, columns=df.columns)]).sort_index()
```

Comment: Hey I want `24` hour time interval for a particular date in this case `2018-04-13`.

Comment: And for another data not?

Comment: basically I will be given a date and then I have to give `cpu` values for 24 hour interval for that date.So there will be 24 values for the particular date.

Comment: @SouvikRay - Is possible remove `NaN`s rows - interval which does not exist?

Comment: I want to keep the intervals that does not exist and assign 0 to it.

Comment: @SouvikRay - I check it again and `df.resample('H')["cpu"].mean().fillna(0)` should working - if data create mean and if no data `NaN`s which are repalce by `0`. Or maybe something dont understand...

Comment: use `s.fillna(0, inplace=True)` instead of `s.dripna()`

Comment: @SouvikRay - So if exist values, are not changed and only added missing hours?

Comment: @jezrael yes exactly